# Mostrar porcentaje en c# mvc

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Tengo un excel que contiene una columna con datos de porcentaje. Este archivo lo importo dentro de mi vista de mvc, sin embargo tal columna que menciono me muestra los datos en decimales.

En SQL realice un query que me convierte estos datos a % al ejecutar mi consulta obtengo el resultado. Este es el query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CapacidadesAll AS SELECT 
ID,
Nombre,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),[% UTILIZACION]*100)+' %' AS [% UTILIZACION] FROM dbo.Capacidad
```

Dentro de mi controlador llame a mi procedimiento almacenado de esta forma y al depurar me trae la información en porcentaje, la columna se llama C_Utilizacion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo en la vista obtengo los datos de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta aquí es:

¿Cómo podría realizar que en mi vista se vea reflejado el resultado que obtengo en la BD y en el controlador como en la imagen anterior?

También me surge la duda, ¿Si en SQL hay un tipo de dato que identifique el porcentaje?

Agradecería mucho de su apoyo y/o comentarios.

Comment: Buen día, la variable con la que recibes el dato por parte de C# que tipo de dato es?

Comment: @KevinBarrios Lo que hice fue llamar mi procedure de esta forma: var all = db.CapacidadGenerals;

Comment: un porcentaje es un numero, que puede estar representado como un entero o como un decimal. No hay un tipo de dato, porque "porcentaje" es una representacion visual de un valor (como tampoco hay un tipo de dato edad, no deja de ser un numero)... lo que tenes que hacer, es convertirlo en tu vista, al formato en que lo queres mostrar.

Comment: @gbianchi Agradezco de tus comentarios. Una pregunta se puede realizar la conversión en una columna, ya que el dato lo tengo de esta forma: <td>@anillos.C__UTILIZACION</td> pregunto porque  es la primera vez que realizo este tipo de ejercicio.

Comment: fijate que en la respuesta que te agregaron esta todo explicado...

Answer (score 2):

Los números los puede formatear, y es comun realizarlo en la vista (asi como te comentan) asi le das el formato final, o puedes tener un propiedad dentro de tu objeto que devuelva el numero formateado.

Puedes darle darle una mirada a [Cadenas con formato numérico personalizado](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings), pero te dejo un ejemplo con el numero de 3 cifras mas abajo de los que puedes formatear

Pero para temas de "%" Porcentajes... que tenemos [especificador "%" personalizado](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier-3), que lo que hace literal:

> Un signo de porcentaje (%) en una cadena de formato hace que se multiplique un número por 100 antes de darle formato. El símbolo de porcentaje adaptado se inserta en el número en la ubicación donde aparece % en la cadena de formato.

Ejemplo

Lo puedes ver al ejemplo online aqui y ejecutarlo https://dotnetfiddle.net/uUxGu0

```
    var number = 0.3520M;
    
    Console.WriteLine(number); //0.352
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"{0:0.#}", number)); //0.4
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"{0:0.##}", number)); //0.35
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"{0:0.###}", number)); //0.352
    
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"{0:0.##} %", number));//0.35 %
    
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"{0:0.##%}", number)); //35.2%
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"{0:0.#0%}", number)); //35.20%
    
    var ciSpanish = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format(ciSpanish,"{0:0.##%}", number)); //35,2%
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format(ciSpanish,"{0:#0.#0%}", number)); //35,20%
```

Especiicamente en ASP.NET MVC nos podemos ayudar con el [atributo DisplayFormat](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute?view=net-6.0) que puedes describir el formato que necesitas con el parametro [DataFormatString](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.dataformatstring?view=net-6.0) y luego al visualizar deberias utilizar la extension [DisplayFor](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

Ejemplo

En tu objeto tendrias que decorar la propiedad con el atributo

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=false)]
public double C__UTILIZACION {get;set;}
```

Y en la vista utilizar

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.C__UTILIZACION)
```

Enlaces que te pueden servir de ayuda

- [Cadenas con formato numérico personalizado](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)
- [Cadenas con formato numérico estándar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía

Comment: Jose A. Fernandez Te agradezco de tu respuesta, estuve revisando el ejemplo que me indicaste, sin embargo llegue a la solución que dentro de mi columna <td>@anillos.C__UTILIZACION</td> realice el siguiente cambio:  
<td>@Convert.ToDouble(anillos.C__UTILIZACION.Value).ToString("0%")</td> incluyendo la parte que me comentaste sobre poner un [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=false)] en mi modelo obtuve el resultado que pretendía. 

Nuevamente te agradezco de tu valiosa aportación